# Kivy: Changing screens in screen manager with an on_press event

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to know how to change screens using an on_press event binded to a button, without using a KV file/KV language.

I have read through the Kivy documentation, but have only been able to find solutions using a KV file.

Example:

`on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'`

I can also change the screen in the main python file using:

`screenmanager.current = 'screen2'`

But I cant figure out how to achieve the same using a button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this is to define your own button subclass:

```
class ScreenButton(Button):
    screenmanager = ObjectProperty()
    def on_press(self, *args):
        super(ScreenButton, self).on_press(*args)
        self.screenmanager.current = 'whatever'
```

The on_press method is automatically called when the button is pressed, so the screenmanager's `current` property will be changed.

Then you can have code something like:

```
sm = ScreenManager()

sc1 = Screen(name='firstscreen')
sc1.add_widget(ScreenButton(screenmanager=sm))

sc2 = Screen(name='whatever')
sc2.add_widget(Label(text='another screen'))

sm.add_widget(sc1)
sm.add_widget(sc2)
```

Clicking the button should switch the screens as required.

Another way (which is probably how kv language actually does it) would be to manually use the `bind` method.

```
def switching_function(*args):
    some_screen_manager.current = 'whatever'

some_button.bind(on_press=switching_function)
```

This would mean that `switching_function` is called whenever `some_button` is pressed. Of course there is a lot of flexibility here regarding how and when you define the function, so (for instance) you could do something more general like pass the screenmanager as the first argument to the function.

I didn't test this code and it isn't a complete app, but hopefully the meaning is clear. Either method should work fine, you can choose the way that seems most sensible. I might construct a more complete example later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the subclass solution helped me achieve what I was trying to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

A working example with two screens, no kv file everything done in Python:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 1", font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 2",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 2",font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 1",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

class TestApp(App):

        def build(self):
            my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
            screen1 = ScreenOne(name='screen1')
            screen2 = ScreenTwo(name='screen2')
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen1)
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen2)
            return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that this won't work with Kivy 1.9.2?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, was to use the `setter` method of EventDispatcher, to get a reference to the setter function for screen_manager.current

```
button.bind(on_press=partial(sm.setter('current'), (sm, 'whatever'))
```

of course, it's not very sexy, that's why kv is often a cleaner solution to these things, but it should work.

ps: in case you don't know about it, `partial` comes from the `functools` module, and it's often useful to build these kind of callbacks with a preloaded parameter.

Comment: I'm fairly new to kivy, so sexiness isn't high on my list. This will come in very handy for me. Thank you.