# Kivy | Can't set 2 buttons on_press binding in screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to set 2 buttons on the same screen as below (as you can see I don't want to use KV) :

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mp = mper.MViewer()
        self.add_widget(self.mp)
        layout = BoxLayout()
        okbtn = Button(text="OK", size_hint_y=None, height='48dp')
        okbtn.bind(on_press=partial(sm.setter('current'), (sm, 'ok')))
        gobtn = Button(text="GO", size_hint_y=None, height='48dp')
        gobtn.bind(on_press=partial(sm.setter('current'), (sm, 'fillid')))
        layout.add_widget(okbtn)
        layout.add_widget(gobtn)
        self.add_widget(layout)
```

I have followed Tshirtman [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516335/2538256).
Those 2 buttons are displayed in my screen, but unfortunately, when I press, I get an error message :

```
ValueError: ScreenManager.current accept only str
```

Where `sm = ScreenManager()`.
What is it that am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is simple, that solution does not work.

Comment: OK, then do you have any solution to propose, or any explanation...?

Comment: Have you tried with the other methods?