# Is it possible to schedule Kivy StringProperty set() method using Clock?

Tags: string, methods, properties, set, kivy

I would like to delay Kivy screen manager transition, which I can do for example like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
#: kivy 1.9.2
#: import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager
#: set base_font_size 25

<MainWidget>:
    manager: screen_manager

    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        transition: sm.NoTransition()
        Screen:
            name: 'screen_one'  
            Button:
                text: 'Screen 1, press to switch to Screen 2'
                font_size: base_font_size
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
                    root.statusmsg = 'Screen 2, press to launch Armageddon'

        Screen:
            name: 'screen_two'
            Button:
                text: root.statusmsg
                font_size: base_font_size
                disabled: True if root.statusmsg == 'Busy launching Armageddon' else False # prevent multiple activation
                on_press:
                    root.deliver_payload()

''')


class MainWidget(FloatLayout):

    statusmsg = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def deliver_payload(self, dt=0):
        if not dt: # called via on_press
            self.statusmsg = 'Busy launching Armageddon'
            # launch Armageddon here
            Clock.schedule_once(self.deliver_payload, 2)
        else: # scheduled via Clock
            self.manager.current = 'screen_one'


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mw=MainWidget() 
        return mw


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

However, manager.current is a Kivy StringProperty and I should be able to assign a new value to it with the set() method and perhaps schedule this with Clock e.g. Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.manager.property('current').set(??, 'screen_one'), 2).
I wasn't able to find documentation for Kivy StringProperty set() method. It seems the method takes two args and the first argument needs to be of type kivy._event.EventDispatcher - according to traceback info that I get when I try some random guesses. Can anyone point to some documentation, or examples of use for the set() method?

EDIT: I realise I did not make it clear what I want to do ultimately - I am asking if it is possible to schedule the Kivy property set() method using Kivy Clock. For example, I am able to toggle a Kivy BooleanProperty like this:

```
if self.property('myboolean').get(self):
    self.property('myboolean').set(self, False)
else:
    self.property('myboolean').set(self, True)
```

But I was not able to schedule the method using Clock. The following line generated no errors but did not have any effect either:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.property('myboolean').set(self, False),0)
```

In the case of Kivy StringProperty set() method, I was not even able to figure out what the 1st argument needed to be, so did not get as far as trying to schedule it with Clock.

FURTHER EDIT:
Although screen manager 'current' is a StringProperty according to documentation, it appears to behave somewhat differently. With a StringProperty I am able to do the following:

```
self.property('statusmsg').set(self, 'Armageddon now')
```

However, attempting something like this with manager.current does not succeed:

```
self.manager.property('current').set(self.manager, 'aux_screen')
```

The error message is:

```
   self.manager.property('current').set(self.manager, 'screen_one')
TypeError: Argument 'obj' has incorrect type (expected kivy._event.EventDispatcher, got kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy)
```

Confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this by chance [Kivy: Changing screens in screen manager with an on_press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491286/kivy-changing-screens-in-screen-manager-with-an-on-press-event) (thank you, Tshirtman) and I now have one answer. The following change gives me what I want - the ability to schedule screen change directly (i.e. without an intermediate method to call):

```
def deliver_payload(self):
    self.statusmsg = 'Busy launching Armageddon'
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.manager.setter('current')(self.manager,'screen_one'), 2)
```

So it appears that for assigning a new value to screen manager's 'current' property, the correct method to use is the 'setter' method (not the 'set' method that I was attempting to use).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new value for a `StringProperty` by simply doing a `self.manager.current = 'some string'`, as you do in your code.

Comment: Using the built-in set() method would allow me to schedule the value assignment directly with Clock, obviating the need for any additional method containing the  self.manager.current = 'some string' assignment. It would be more elegant..